# Python making command and arguments shorten

Tags: python

I run `>python -m unittest discover test/vx/ -v` this command for running all unit tests in my project folder.

and I want to make the command shorter like,

`>python run-all-tests`

If I run that command, I wish it runs `>python -m unittest discover test/vx/ -v`, like shortcut.

How can I make it possible? (I'm using Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a better (and easier) solution.

```
alias run-all-tests='python -m unittest discover test/vx/ -v'
```

Then you can simply say

```
run-all-tests
```

Without the python at the front. Add the `alias` to your `$HOME/.bashrc` so it "persists".

Alternatively, you could write your own shell script and check the argument is `run-all-tests` if it is invoke the desired behavior. Otherwise, invoke the real python. I don't much like that approach, so I'd stick with the alias.